# Mysql compare two tables and match some of the columns value and extract data

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

It seems tricky for me to do but here it is. I got two tables named `xp_guru_properties` and `xp_pn_resale`. In the `xp_pn_resale` table, I got colums `block` and `type` and in the table `xp_guru_properties` I got a column `property_name` and `json`. I want to match the two columns and get the specific data in the column `json` from `xp_guru_properties`. Here are some sample data in order for you to not get confused

xp_pn_resale 
[image: my]

xp_guru_properties, This time I searched one data referring to xp_pn_resale table
[image]

the `json` field in table

```
{
  "id": 8174,
  "typeCode": "HDB",
  "name": "111 Lengkong Tiga",
  "newLaunch": false,
  "description": "111 Lengkong Tiga",
  "totalUnits": null,
  "floors": 0,
  "topMonth": null,
  "topYear": 1988,
  "tenure": "L99",
  "coverImageId": 3196890,
  "districtCode": "D14",
  "postcode": "410111",
  "streetname": "Lengkong Tiga",
  "streetname2": null,
  "streetnumber": "111",
  "longitude": 103.9114385,
  "latitude": 1.324030239,

}
```

I just want to get or extract the `postcode` from json whenever I got a match from `xp_resale` to `guru_properties` table. Like I want to match `111 Lengkong Tega` from two tables then I should get `postcode: 410111`. But it seems hard because I need to concat the `block` and `street_name` from `xp_resale` to match the `property_name` from `guru_properties`. Can somebody got any idea? Thanks in advance. Badly need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a join and a json extraction:

```
select json_extract(g.json, '$.postcode') postcode
from xp_pn_resale p
inner join xp_guru_properties g 
    on g.property_name = concat(p.block, ' ', p.street_name)
```

`json_extract(g.json, '$.postcode')` can also be written: `g.json->'$.postcode'`.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. Can you please explain further to me? Do i need to need to use `like` to compare right? even I concat

Comment: What if I need to get all the `postcode` from `guru_properties` with the `like` keyword only searching in `street_name` column sir?

Comment: @Vince: you would change the `on` condition of the `join` to : `g.property_name like concat('%', p.street_name)`.

Comment: yes i did that. thanks a lot. I also added  `json_extract(g.json, '$.name') name` to get the `name` from `guru_properties` so that I got two columns as a result.

Comment: @Vince: this query is yours now!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me sir!! . @GMB.

Comment: can I have a chat with you? Need some little thing to teach me with this.